# Passing a cookie using cURL to a website

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Some website I need to make a request to, using cURL in PHP, contains a captcha, which can be deactivated via setting a cookie "downloadcaptcha=1". Now how do I pass that cookie to the website on a cURL request? Before, you mark as duplicate, I've already made research and came across to using cookie jar files. I have never done something like that and couldn't find any newbie-friendly documentation.

The JS-equivalent code of setting the cookie, taken from the website's function that disables captchas:

```
var exdate=new Date();
var exdays = 1;
var c_name = "downloadcaptcha";
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(1) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value+";path=/";
window.location.reload();
```

I don't want to necessarily make it expire in 1 day. 
Help is appreciated.

Comment: Has `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: downloadcaptcha=1"));` did not work?

Comment: @Tals Yes, it didn't work

Comment: Can you supply an example of your PHP code or the errors you got?

Comment: I didn't get any error, just the website didn't read the cookie and requested a captcha. The js code I posted is what the website does to set the cookie

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you tried settings this cookie in your browser and checking that the Captcha actually disappears? Perhaps there is some Javascript code that handles this?

Comment: @Tals just tried. Yep, just doing document.cookie = "downloadcaptcha=1" works

Comment: Weird. Can you look at the HTTP request coming out from your computer by using [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/), [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

Answer (score 0):

> Here's the output. Not a single mention of the cookie

Request Header is missing the Cookie:

```
Host: www.emuparadise.me
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Referer: https://m.emuparadise.me/
```

Change the $request to:

```
$cookie = '[downloadcaptcha=1'

$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.emuparadise.me";
$request[] = "Accept: */*";
$request[] = "Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip";
$request[] = "Referer: https://m.emuparadise.me/";
$request[] = "Cookie: $cookie";
```

---

> I have tried that already but the website still asks for a captcha.
>   Take a look at the JS code I posted. It's taken from the website's
>   function to disable captchas

I could help you much better if I had a URL to test with.

If there is a redirect you must use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

You may have to make the HTTP Request Header look identical to the JS HTTP header.

You need to look at the cURL HTTP request and response and compare it to the JS HTTP request and response.

To see the JS  HTTP request and response:

- right click the page
- Select Inspect (Chrome) or Insect Element (FireFox)
- Select "Network" tab
- Go to the page with the JS request or if already there Refresh.

---

### Trouble shooting PHP code:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);


$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $info = rawurldecode(var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true));

  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $responseHeader= substr($data,0,$skip);
  $response = substr($data,$skip);
   var_export($info);
  echo "----------------------------------\n$responseHeader\n--------------------------\n$response \n------------------------------------\n";

}
```

---

**Original Post**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie );
```

Single Cookie

```
$cookie = 'CookieName=CookieValue'
```

Multiple Cookies separated by semi-colon.  There is no semi-colon after the last cookie.

```
$cookie = 'CookieName=CookieValue; CookieName=CookieValue' 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie );
```

---

Cookies can also be set using `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`
See last line of the following example.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);

$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.example.com";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
$request[] = "Cookie: $cookie";
```

Comment: I have tried that already but the website still asks for a captcha. Take a look at the JS code I posted. It's taken from the website's function to disable captchas

Comment: using JS it does not make any HTTP request. It just sets a cookie by changing document.cookie. I've tried just doing `document.cookie = "downloadcaptcha=1"` and it works, but I have to do it through my server using PHP and cURL

Comment: Here's the output. Not a single mention of the cookie: https://pastebin.com/raw/Y6Pk5Y4n

Comment: It does a request when `window.location.reload();` is executed, I added instruction to view this request.

Comment: Ok. Will take a look tomorrow